# SingleChildScrollView with child Column isnt scrolling

Tags: flutter

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 95,
            child: PageView.builder(
              itemCount: 7,
              onPageChanged: (value) => onPageChanged(value),
              controller: _pageController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Date(index: index + MyHomePage.offset,),
            ),
          ),
          Training()
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

This is the code.

I even tried the option with ListView, but it wont scroll. Note: When I open keyboard it scrolls down.

Comment: I've replaced `Training` and it is working, Can you include more about `Training` and details

Comment: what platform do you run your code on?

Comment: @pskink  I've tested on web

Comment: @pskink Its running on android emulator.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Training is a ListView with Containers inside of it.

Comment: Do you like to have full body scrollable or just ListView?

Comment: I would like whole body.

Answer (score 0):

The parent `SingleChildScrollView` is already handling scroll event and the inner `Training` having ListView, you can set `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`.

Or you can use Column widget  instead of ListView on `Training()`.

Also you can use ListView in-place of SingleChildScrollView.

```dart
body: ListView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 95,
        child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: 7,
          onPageChanged: (value) => onPageChanged(value),
          controller: _pageController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Date(
            index: index + MyHomePage.offset,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      //On `Training()`
      Column(
        children: items.map((d) => Text(d)).toList(),
      )
    ],
  ),
```